# How to find the package to which a certain file belongs in a Debian-based distribution?

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

Where are the [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) files in Linux?

I want use lib like safe-read, mbchar, etc... in my project but I do not find them on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine.

Comment: GNU coreutils is a set of utility programs (`rm`, `ls`, `cat`, `diff`, and so on, roughly 100 total).  It's not related to the library routines you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-file` is your friend:

```
x@y:~$ apt-file search safe-read
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/lib/safe-read.c
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/lib/safe-read.h
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/m4/safe-read.m4
gnulib: /usr/share/gnulib/modules/safe-read
```

Use `sudo apt-get install gnulib` (in this case) to install the missing dependency. Run

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

once to initialize the file index.

Comment: This answer is correct, but gnulib is *very bad* software and not something you should copy into your own code. Not only is it full of hacks and non-portable constructs (often with 10 different versions of the same non-portable hack for every known 1980s-era legacy system, rather than just writing a clean portable version), but it's also full of bad designs like interfaces that abort the calling program whenever they fail...

Comment: @R..: thanks for the note about gnulib's stability and design; that kind of knowledge can otherwise take eons to acquire. :)

Comment: I encourage reading `freadahead.c`, `freading.c`, etc. for anyone who doesn't want to take my word on it. They're full of code that pokes at the internals of the `FILE` structure on every known platform, and they have a default case at the end that claims to be slow-but-portable, which instead of containing any working code, contains a lone `#error` line... These are just the first examples that come to mind; there are plenty more.

Comment: R.. thanks, I'm already reading docs on your suggestions :) but now I am forced to use this lib, then replace it with something better :)
Now they're giving me a problem with config.h (sigh)